# How does augmenting ancient items work?

Tags: diablo-iii

A new recipe to the cube was added with the 2.4 update, which is augmenting ancient items.

[image: Augmenting Recipe]

The recipe is pretty clear, but I saw people ruining their items by adding wrong stats (intelligence on demon hunter etc.). Is it related to the gems' types?

For example, if I used Royal Emeralds, would I get dexterity (considering it is an armor piece)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So basically what this recipe does is it makes your current ancient item better.

The legendary gems are the important component in this recipe; you receive +5 points to an attribute chosen by Flawless Royal gem (Amethyst for Vit, Ruby for Strength, Emerald for Dex, Topaz for Int, regardless of item type)  for every rank of your legendary gem. So, a rank 50 legendary gem will give you an additional 250 to your main stat (chosen by normal gem type). You aren't able to augment twice to double the effect though, if you augment a second time it just overwrites the first augment.

The whole purpose of this is to just inch closer and closer to complete [BiS (Best In Slot)](https://www.diablowiki.net/BiS).

Hope this helped.

Comment: If a second augmentation overwrites the first, that means you can't 'ruin' an item, right? If you accidentally augment with the wrong normal gem type, you can just do it again with the right type (admittedly after levelling another legendary gem up).

Comment: Which "main stat" do I get if I put in an Amethyst?

Comment: Yep Rensa, you can't "ruin" items but you can mess up and have to re-level a gem all over again. Orc JMR: it depends on which slot you're augmenting, if you augment a weapon with an Amethyst you'll get x+ life per hit. Just use the gems slots as a reference and you'll be all good.

Comment: This page http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/items/kanais-cube#augment-ancient says you are wrong, and you won't get Life Per Hit.

Comment: Yes but the **main** stat is obviously what you're picking, which in return, **SHOULD** be your main stat. You're not going to gem intellect for a barb. Yes, my apologies - you only gain main stat points (which is what my original comment said) not life per hit etc.

Comment: @infek well you could also grab intelligence for resist all for a barb, which could be quite useful if your damage is already good enough.

Comment: @Matthew I wasn't aware that was implemented; on last years PTR you weren't able to use them. Is it changed now?

Comment: So the gem rank requirement is just a minimum? Eg: rank 51 would give +255 to attribute? That seems useful (if a little grind-y)

Comment: Correct; from the page in Orc's link above, "The higher the rank of the Legendary Gem used, the more attribute points will be added to your item."

Answer (score 10):

These augments are extremely important for endgame content. They are one of the keys to progressing into the upper greater rifts.

As the accepted answer states, you get +5 for every rank of the gem.

The end result is a unique blue stat name on your item called "Caldesann's Despair" (the name of the cube recipe for augmenting), as well as the rank and bonus to the stat.

So, for example, let's say you used a level 42 legendary gem with an emerald, the added blue stat would be:

> +210 Dexterity (Caldesann's Despair Rank 42)

These are the correlations for gems to stats:

- ruby (red): strength,
- amethyst (purple): vitality,
- emerald (green): dexterity,
- topaz (yellow): intelligence
- diamond (white): not available

Having enough gems is important. You should be taking your off stat gems (as in, if you are a Demon Hunter and don't use Topaz) and using [Convert Gem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/346812/25404) to get them to your main stat type.

- If you want to augment a weapon, the legendary gem you use must be *at least* rank 30.
- If you want to augment jewelry, the legendary gem you use must be *at least* rank 40.
- If you want to augment armor, the legendary gem you use must be *at least* rank 50.

This doesn't mean that you should use a 30, 40, or 50 rank gem though. This means that once you reach grift 30, you should absolutely augment your weapon if it is ancient, and then every 5-10 grifts re-augment it.

The same goes for jewelry and armor. By 60 you may be augmenting every several grift levels you earn, as each +5 or +10 is noticeable during progression.