# What happens to my legendary gem after an ancient augmentation?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3 you can **[augment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253019/how-does-augmenting-ancient-items-work)** your ancient legendary items. Apparently you can augment each item multiple times and it just gets overwritten by the newer one.

My question is: What happens to the legendary gem I use for the augmentation?

Is it consumed in the process? If yes does it drop again or will it be lost forever?

Comment: Easiest way to farm certain gems is to create a second character, put the gem you want a second of in that chars inventory. Then do a greater rift with the other character and you will get a new Gem, you can then repeat the process to get more.

Comment: @Lyrion or drop it on the ground. Or use any of the many completely worthless LGems for augments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The legendary gem is consumed.

Legendary gems will continue to drop in Grifts as long as you don't have a copy of that gem on your active character, their companion, or in your stash.

Note that the list above is exhaustive. If a gem is on another of your characters or on the ground, it can drop in a GRift.

Comment: I think legendary gems are tied to the character they dropped for, you can definitely get copies on different characters even if the copy is in the stash, though I haven't really tested what happens if you have two copies and destroy one, whether either character can get a new copy.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian no it isn't and no you can't. If there is a gem in your stash, that gem will NEVER drop. If a new character is wearing "someone else's" BotP, BotP will not drop.

Comment: Did that change in a recent patch?  It would definitely be a welcome change (although I still think legendary gems should just be put in a currency tab).

Comment: @IllusiveBrian no, they've always worked like that. You must be misremembering and/or were mistaken about the circumstances at the time. Or a bug happened.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I shouldn't say "always," I started RoS in season 2 and that's how they worked the