# How to get the best gear in Diablo Reaper Of Souls

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I just finished the Diablo 3 story, playing as a Demon Hunter. I have decided that my next goal is to get the best gear, or at least as good as possible.

I am aware that what is considered "best" changes when new items are added. But likely the path to the best gear does not.

Therefore, my question is: What steps are required to get the best gear?

Comment: This question is very vague with no level of research shown.  What part of the game are you in?  What's you character's level/paragon level?  Do you mean which sets are best or what stats are best?  Are you running solo or in a group?  Do you want to be tanky or a glass cannon?

Comment: While it's difficult to say what combination of items is objectively 'best'; esp. in a changing landscape, efficient and effective technique to get to as high a difficulty level as you can likely contains some core useful knowledge ('how can I get to the endgame'). This question is worded poorly, but does have a limited set of useful solutions.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to play main story, don't bother looking for the best gear. You can complete the game with any items.

If you want to play endgame, you will probably want to build your character being able to complete high levels of Greater Rifts. Top players manage to complete GR150, for novice players - it's good to aim into GR90-100.

---

In current game version there are two types of endgame gear:

1. Set based builds. Your goal is to complete full set of character specific gear. Sets have some ridiculous modificators to damage of some skills, like "Skill X now deals 10000% more damage". Once you complete the set, you aim for additional items that affect the same skill or generally improve your character.
2. Legacy of Nightmares (LoN) or Legacy of Dreams (LoD) builds. In contrast with previous, they rely on your character not having any class set items equipped. They gain bonuses for each Legendary / Ancient item equipped. So you are free to equip any Legendary items, but better results will be if you are stacking items affecting the same skill.

---

What builds are the best? Nobody knows, meta changes every season. But you can view seasonal leaderboards to check what gear top players use - [Demon Hunters Leaderboard](https://us.diablo3.com/en-us/rankings/era/13/rift-dh)

---

So how to get there:

1. Play in season, reach 70 level, complete some season journey challenges - you will be required to play low Torment difficulty levels and will need to complete some beginner levels of Greater Rifts (20-30) - and you will receive a full set for your character as Haedrig's Gift - 3 packs with 2 set items each.
2. With full set you can go into higher Torment levels and also higher Greater Rifts. Find some guide to follow, for example, [this site](https://www.icy-veins.com/d3/demon-hunter-builds) has some Demon Hunter builds available.
3. Run Normal/Greater Rifts all day: You will eventually have enough gear to complete any build. Feel free to stick to your initial set or go for any other set or even for some LoN/LoD build.
4. Run Normal/Greater Rifts all day: You will eventually replace all your items with Ancient/Primal versions, which are basically same items but with better stats.
5. Run Normal/Greater Rifts all day to level legendary gems: you will eventually augment all your Ancient/Primal items with Caldesann's Despair cube recipe (see [How does augmenting ancient items work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/253019/144891))
6. Congratulations, you now have the Best Gear Ever. Now you can run more Greater Rifts!

Comment: This really is a good answer and hope this question can be salvaged.

Comment: I believe some bounties are needed to complete the first few season journeys to receive your free set. But don't despair! You don't have to do all those bounties at once, you can do some Normal/Greater Rifts inbetween ;)

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the gear to put together a build, you'll want to start targeting upgrades to specific items with one of a couple systems available.

1. Kadala - Kadala trades blood shards (which drop from rifts) for a random piece of gear.  She will sell random armor for only 25 shards, compared to 50 shards for a ring, 75 for a weapon and 100 for an amulet.  For this reason, you'll usually want to target your armor upgrades by buying that slot from Kadala.  Rings are also OK to target but half as efficient, and weapons/amulets are effectively never efficient to buy from her unless you need to get your first copy of a particular legendary weapon/amulet or want to generate rare items to upgrade on the cube (and don't care about upgrading your armor).
2. Reforge Legendary recipe (Kanai's Cube) - On Kanai's Cube, there is a recipe called "Reforge Legendary Item" which lets you take an existing legendary item and "Reforge" it, effectively re-rolling it like it was a new drop.  Once you have a second copy of a legendary item you need, you'll use this to reforge the worse one until it's better than your other one, and switch.  This is especially useful for items that need a lot of specific rolls to be usable and are inefficient to buy from Kadala.  Weapons are a prime candidate for this given the possible range of weapon damage rolls.  Legendary items have a 10% chance to be ancient and a 1% chance to be primal ancient, so if you do it enough you'll most likely eventually get a primal ancient variant of the item you are reforging.  Note that you have to run a level 70 greater rift solo to get primal ancient items to drop, do not use this until you've done that so you have a chance at the reforge to be primal ancient.
3. Upgrade rare item (Kanai's Cube) - Since this can upgrade a rare into any regularly dropped legendary of that type, it tends to be less useful once you already have the legendary items you need.  With that said, it uses different materials from Reforge Legendary Item so if you have a glut of basic crafting materials it can be worth using to try to get a better copy of your amulet or weapons.  It may also be useful to try and upgrade your bracers if your bracers have a wide variance on their legendary power (Demon Hunters in particular almost always use Wraps of Hatred which can vary between 40%-50% damage reduction), since you usually want your bracers to also have +6% critical strike chance and +elemental damage, and there tend to be fewer legendary bracer types available than other armor slots.